# TypeORM: edit a many-to-many relations with custom properties

Tags: sql, many-to-many, typeorm

How can I edit a entity with many-to-many relations with custom properties?
Typeorm docs examples are very limited for this type of relationship:
https://typeorm.io/#/many-to-many-relations/many-to-many-relations-with-custom-properties

I have 3 tables: users, roles, user_roles

User.ts

```js
@Entity('users')
class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  email: string;
  
  @OneToMany(() => UserRole, userRole => userRole.user, {
    cascade: true,
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
  })
  @JoinColumn({ referencedColumnName: 'user_id' })
  userRoles!: UserRole[];
}

export default User;
```

Role.ts

```js
@Entity('roles')
class Role {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
  id: number;

  @Column()
  role: string;

  @OneToMany(() => UserRole, userRole => userRole.role, {
    cascade: true,
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
  })
  @JoinColumn({ referencedColumnName: 'role_id' })
  userRoles!: UserRole[];
}

export default Role;
```

UserRole.ts

```js
@Entity('user_roles')
class UserRole {
 @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
 id: number;

 @Column()
 user_id!: number;

 @Column()
 role_id!: number;
 
 @CreateDateColumn()
 created_at: Date;

 @UpdateDateColumn()
 updated_at: Date;

 @ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.userRoles)
 @JoinColumn({ name: 'user_id' })
 user!: User;

 @ManyToOne(() => Role, role => role.userRoles)
 @JoinColumn({ name: 'role_id' })
 role!: Role;
}

export default UserRole;
```

Create a user with related userRoles is working:

```js
const user = {
  name: 'Test user',
  email: 'testuser@test.com',
  userRoles: [
    { role_id: 1 },
    { role_id: 2 }, 
    { role_id: 3 },
    { role_id: 4 }
  ],
};

await this.usersRepository.save(user);
```

Update its not working, I want to replace all related user_roles with the new ones, is there any save strategy option in typeorm many to many relation? I have seen in other orms for example ‘replace’ or ‘append‘ option in relation definition
This is how im trying to update:

```js
// load user
const user = await this.usersRepository.findById(user_id);

/*
returns:

User {
 id: 2,
 name: 'Test user',
 email: 'testuser@test.com',
 userRoles: [
   UserRole {
     id: 376,
     user_id: 2,
     role_id: 1,
     created_at: 2020-09-18T17:26:52.000Z,
     updated_at: 2020-09-18T17:26:52.000Z
   },
   UserRole {
     id: 377,
     user_id: 2,
     role_id: 2,
     created_at: 2020-09-18T17:26:52.000Z,
     updated_at: 2020-09-18T17:26:52.000Z
   },
   UserRole {
     id: 378,
     user_id: 2,
     role_id: 3,
     created_at: 2020-09-18T17:26:53.000Z,
     updated_at: 2020-09-18T17:26:53.000Z
   },
   UserRole {
     id: 379,
     user_id: 2,
     role_id: 4,
     created_at: 2020-09-18T17:26:53.000Z,
     updated_at: 2020-09-18T17:26:53.000Z
   }
 ]
}
*/

// edit user
const newRolesIds = [4, 5, 6, 7];

user.name = 'updated name';
user.email = 'updatedemail@test.com';


// isn`t it suposed to replace old user_roles and create this new ones?
user.userRoles = newRolesIds.map(roleId => {
 // keep the roles that are already saved in database and are in the newRolesIds 
     const existingRole = user.userRoles.find(userRole => userRole.role_id === roleId);

     if (existingRole) {
       return existingRole;
     }

     // add new roles
     const userRole = new UserRole();
     userRole.user_id = user.id;
     userRole.role_id = roleId;
     return userRole;
});

/*
user after edit:
User {
 id: 2,
 name: 'updated name',
 email: 'updatedemail@test.com',
 userRoles: [
   UserRole { user_id: 2, role_id: 4 },
   UserRole { user_id: 2, role_id: 5 },
   UserRole { user_id: 2, role_id: 6 },
 ]
}
*/

this.ormRepository.save(user);
```

Save fails with this sql error:
Its a strange update sql, not recognizing user_id and role_id is not even present in sql, am I forgetting to define something in relationships?

```sh
QueryFailedError: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`user_roles`, CONSTRAINT `UserRoleUserIdFK` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
  code: 'ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_2',
  errno: 1452,
  sqlState: '23000',
  sqlMessage: 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`user_roles`, CONSTRAINT `UserRoleUserIdFK` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)',
  query: 'UPDATE `user_roles` SET `user_id` = ?, `updated_at` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE `id` = ?',
  parameters: [ undefined, 376 ]
```

sql log shows insert for new roles 5, 6, 7 and after that its trying to update the roles 1,2,3 that should be deleted throwing a sql error

according to the docs it is only necessary remove from the array to delete or should i do this delete manually?
https://typeorm.io/#/many-to-many-relations/deleting-many-to-many-relations

```sql
query: SELECT `user_roles`.`id` AS `id`, `user_roles`.`user_id` AS `user_id` FROM `user_roles` `user_roles` WHERE ((`user_roles`.`user_id` = ?)) -- PARAMETERS: [2]
query: START TRANSACTION
query: INSERT INTO `user_roles`(`id`, `user_id`, `role_id`, `created_at`) VALUES (DEFAULT, ?, ?, DEFAULT) -- PARAMETERS: [2,5]
query: SELECT `UserRole`.`id` AS `UserRole_id`, `UserRole`.`created_at` AS `UserRole_created_at` FROM `user_roles` `UserRole` WHERE `UserRole`.`id` = ? -- PARAMETERS: [7]
query: INSERT INTO `user_roles`(`id`, `user_id`, `role_id`, `created_at`) VALUES (DEFAULT, ?, ?, DEFAULT) -- PARAMETERS: [2,6]
query: SELECT `UserRole`.`id` AS `UserRole_id`, `UserRole`.`created_at` AS `UserRole_created_at` FROM `user_roles` `UserRole` WHERE `UserRole`.`id` = ? -- PARAMETERS: [8]
query: INSERT INTO `user_roles`(`id`, `user_id`, `role_id`, `created_at`) VALUES (DEFAULT, ?, ?, DEFAULT) -- PARAMETERS: [2,7]
query: SELECT `UserRole`.`id` AS `UserRole_id`, `UserRole`.`created_at` AS `UserRole_created_at` FROM `user_roles` `UserRole` WHERE `UserRole`.`id` = ? -- PARAMETERS: [9]
query: UPDATE `user_roles` SET `user_id` = ? WHERE `id` = ? -- PARAMETERS: [null,1]
query: UPDATE `user_roles` SET `user_id` = ? WHERE `id` = ? -- PARAMETERS: [null,2]
query: UPDATE `user_roles` SET `user_id` = ? WHERE `id` = ? -- PARAMETERS: [null,3]

query failed: UPDATE `user_roles` SET `user_id` = ? WHERE `id` = ? -- PARAMETERS: [null,1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figuredout that typeorm currently don't support updates this way. The default behavior is set the related records keys to null instead of delete it and in my case this behavior dont work because the related have a FK with index. There are a PR to add this feature to delete related records instead of set null:
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/pull/7105

The workaround is delete manually the unused records before update

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should also do an extra query to your DB and fetch the **relationship** data, and then assign them to the "main" Entity, which in your case is User. The update as you see fails because the `user_id` is equal to `NULL`. If I were you I would use the [**Active Record pattern**](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/active-record-data-mapper.md) for DB operations witH **TypeORM**. It is more easy and practical to use, due to the fact that itself manages the connection with the DB.

Comment: Im already using active record, and the relationship data is loaded with user entity find. Check the sql log part, the new roles data have the correct insert with user_id and role_id. The error occurs for the old data that shoul be deleted and is not present anymore in relation array, but for some reason is not being deleted but is trying to update with user_id null

Comment: The query shows `query: UPDATE 'user_roles' SET 'user_id' = ? WHERE 'id' = ? -- PARAMETERS: [null,1]', which means that the `user_id = NULL`.

Comment: This is the query that throws the error, check the last code part, its is the complete sql log sequence showing the correct inserts and after that this updates with null which I think should be the delete that never occurs

Comment: I think that the update does not execute because the `user_id = NULL`, and the delete operation is after update one.

Comment: It doesn't make sense, why update on a line that should be deleted?
The 3 lines with user_id null update are the roles removed from the relationship array there is no point in updating they should be deleted. That's why I suspect there are something wrong with the relationship setup

Comment: Yeah it is possible, especially if you change the *migrations* files or set up a DB on your own.